# c++14 template specialization "used but never defined"

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, warnings, constexpr

To define template for compile-time recursion, I've to define 2 templates, one normal template, and another one which is for "initial" case like this:

```
template<int i>
struct Int {};

constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>;

template<int i>
constexpr auto iter(Int<i>) -> decltype(auto) {
    return iter(Int<i-1>{});
}

int main() {
    decltype(iter(Int<10>{})) a;
    return 0;
}
```

But gcc gives a warning:

```
warning: inline function 'constexpr Int<0> iter(Int<0>)' used but never defined
constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>;
```

Why there's such a warning?

Comment: Because it's *true*? The non-template declaration and the template definition are two different functions. The non-template declaration is only a declaration, that function is used but never defined.

Comment: Perhaps what you really meant to do is to specialize the template, instead of declaring a non-template function that happens to have the same name as a templated function; but otherwise has absolutely has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Extending @SamVarshavchik: Actually it is fine to stop template recursion with a non-template *overload*. Just that you should be *aware* what you are doing (overloading vs. specialisation)...

Comment: Careful with `int` as template parameter: `Int<-1>` would get funny (well, actually resulting in UB for signed integer underflow - if compiler doesn't break earlier for exceeding maximum recursion depths anyway). Better either switch to unsigned type or handle negative values explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have declared the function

```
constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>;
```

but you never defined it, i.e. there is no body.

Maybe you wanted to write:

```
constexpr auto iter(Int<0>) -> Int<0>
{
    return Int<0>{};
}
```

But this looks like an XY problem to me. I don't see why you would like to use recursion like that, when you can write a simple loop in a constexpr function instead.